# How can I simplify this python statements

Tags: python, django

There's a model represents BBS.

I want to make change the value without update database. because I want to preserve the database value. To be precise at display time, I want it to be displayed as  `'[collabo]' + article.title` this is what I am doing at the moment.

below is combine '[collabo]' and all of title with for loop

```
for article in articles:
    article.title = '[collabo]'+article.title
```

is there any way to change the title value at one line of code? I don't want to change or update database. Or is there a better way.

Comment: I know but I'm finding a way shortest code like this. article.title = '[xxx]' + F('title') but this is not work. any way thanks for advice.

Comment: What is the usecase? Why would you want to save the result in `article.title`, but not store in the database? If you want to represent this in the template, then you can add the prefix there instead of in the view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in a single database query it's one line longer than what you have now!! but it's far more efficient.

```
from django.db.models import Value 
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Article.objects.annotate(new_title = Concat(V('[collabo]'),'title')))
```

The [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) method in the queryset is your friend here (with a little help from Concat and Value)

You could also do this at the template level

articles = Article.objects.all()
   render('template.html',{'articles': articles})

And then

```
{% for article in articles %}
    [collabo] {{ article.title }}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may work with methods of the model class to give specific modification you want.

## models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    # some fields ...

    def edited_title(self):
       return '[collabo] {}'.format(self.title)
```

then you can exploit it in the templates with `{{article.edited_title}}`.